# How do I encapsulate this java code that uses 'instanceof'?

Tags: java, encapsulation, instanceof

How do I encapsulate code that uses 'instanceof' ，
I have a lot of types to judge, how do I simplify them ? For example using for loops.

```
            if (obj instanceof UserLogin) {
                continue;
            }
            if (obj instanceof MultipartFile) {
                continue;
            }
            if (obj instanceof Part) {
                continue;
            }
            if (obj instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                continue;
            }
            if (obj instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                continue;
            }


   //【Simplify using for loops :】
```

My idea is: add the classes you want to judge to a ignoreList collection and iterate using Instanceof.
But have error :Cannot resolve symbol 'get'

```
public boolean shouldIgnore(Object obj) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ignoreList.size(); i++) {
        if (obj instanceof ignoreList.get (i) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The `instanceof` operator requires a type name not a `Class` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Class` objects and use the `isInstance` method to check if an object is an instance of a particular class:

```
public static boolean shouldIgnore(Object obj, Class<?>[] ignoreList) {
    for (Class c : ignoreList) {
        if (c.isInstance(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
shouldIgnore(new Integer(10), new Class<?>[] { Number.class, String.class })
```

If you prefer to use `List<Class<?>>` instead of an array, it works just as well. Change the method signature to:

```
public static boolean shouldIgnore(Object obj, List<Class<?>> ignoreList)
```

and invoke it like:

```
shouldIgnore(10, List.of(Number.class, String.class))
```

Comment: Nice Answer. Personally I prefer using `List.of` rather than arrays. Would the generics work similarly? Maybe `List< Class<?> >` and `List.of( Number.class, String.class )`?  (I have yet to master the wildcards and `extends` in Generics.)

Comment: Yes, a `List<Class<?>>` works just as well here.